# What size rim is OK?

Tags: mountain-bike

I have a 700x35c rear rim, it's bent pretty bad, but only can find 700x38c rims, is that ok to use? Or should I keep hunting for the same size rim?

Comment: Unless there's something special about the hub and spokes you already have, and you have the skill required to build a wheel, you probably just want to buy a new wheel. (Or should we read "xyz rim" as "wheel with xyz rim"?)

Comment: Unless the hub in the busted wheel is a higher-end one, it's almost certainly more cost-effective to just buy a new wheel.  It's unfortunate, but the lack of economies of scale for labor and the shipping of parts tends to make buying a whole new wheel cheaper than getting all the parts and then paying someone to rebuild the wheel.  There's not much difference between shipping one rim and shipping one complete wheel.  Even if you do the rebuild yourself, just the parts and the shipping might be more than an entire new wheel. (Been there, done that...)

Comment: What size tyre will you be fitting?

Comment: 35 and 38 are huge for rim and coincidentally common tire sizes. Are you sure about the numbers?

Answer (score 2):

If the width of tires you want to run are a little narrow for a 35mm rim, a 38mm rim could cause problems, otherwise there are no issues I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

A 700x38 rim will be OK. Be aware that your new rim needs to be drilled for the same number of spokes as your old rim, and your existing spokes might not fit it.